# Animation of stroke of circle segment ends in complete stroke

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to animate the appearance of a segment of a circle. To archive this I use a CABasicAnimations which works quiet fine.

The animation starts on top and moves quiet nicely to one third of the whole circle. But when the animation finishes, the circle is being drawn completely immediately.

How can I prevent that?

Here is the source code of my custom UIView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    int radius = 100;
    int strokeWidth = 10;
    CGColorRef color = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    int timeInSeconds = 5;

    CGFloat startAngle = 0;
    CGFloat endAngle = 0.33;

    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

    circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-radius, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-radius);

    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    circle.strokeColor = color;
    circle.lineWidth = strokeWidth;

    [self.layer addSublayer:circle];

    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = timeInSeconds;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:startAngle];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:endAngle];

    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you apply an animation to a layer, Core Animation creates a copy of the layer and animates the properties of the copy.  The original layer is called the *model layer* and the copy is called the *presentation layer*.  An animation never changes the properties of the model layer.

You tried to fix this by setting `removedOnCompletion` to `NO`.  You would also have to set the `fillMode` of the animation to make this work, but it's not really the correct way to animate a property.

The correct way is to change the property on your model layer, then apply the animation.

```
// Change the model layer's property first.
circle.strokeEnd = endAngle;

// Then apply the animation.
CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
drawAnimation.duration            = timeInSeconds;
drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:startAngle];
drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:endAngle];
drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
```

This is explained in the [*Core Animation Essentials* video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011-421/) from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).  I highly recommend watching it.

Comment: Any idea about progress %(0 to 1)  during `drawAnimation.duration` ?