# CAShapeLayer fillcolor arc animation not working

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am using below code to draw a Pie slice layer with CAShapeLayer.

```
CGFloat endAngle = (M_PI*2/5)-M_PI_2;

CAShapeLayer *outerBorderCircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
int outerradius = self.frame.size.width/2;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(outerradius, outerradius)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(outerradius, self.outerCircleBorder)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(outerradius,outerradius) radius:outerradius-self.outerCircleBorder startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
[path closePath];
outerBorderCircle.path = path.CGPath;

outerBorderCircle.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
outerBorderCircle.strokeColor = self.borderShadowColor.CGColor;
outerBorderCircle.lineWidth = self.outerCircleBorder;
outerBorderCircle.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
outerBorderCircle.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;

CABasicAnimation *startanimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"fillColor"];
startanimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
startanimation.fromValue = (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
startanimation.toValue = (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
startanimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
startanimation.duration = 10.0;
[startanimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];

[outerBorderCircle addAnimation:startanimation forKey:@"fillColor"];

[self.layer addSublayer:outerBorderCircle];
```

But animation part working as fade in fade out. But i need to animate arc kind of animation.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To animate the stroke you should animate those properties:

`-strokeStart`

`-strokeEnd`

From the documentation:

> Combined with the strokeEnd property, this property defines the
>   subregion of the path to stroke. The value in this property indicates
>   the relative point along the path at which to begin stroking while the
>   strokeEnd property defines the end point. A value of 0.0 represents
>   the beginning of the path while a value of 1.0 represents the end of
>   the path. Values in between are interpreted linearly along the path
>   length.

**[UPDATE]**

```
CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
drawAnimation.duration            = timeInSeconds;
drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:startAngle];
drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:endAngle];
drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
```

Credits to [Rob Mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142888/animation-of-stroke-of-circle-segment-ends-in-complete-stroke)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Can you please send me a sample code.